# How to view inside of a function body

Tags: r, function

I want to extract the contents of the `server` argument of a script that calls `shinyApp()` for my package [shinyobjects](https://rjake.github.io/shinyobjects/)

If I have this code:

```
code <- 
  'library(tidyverse)
  library(shiny)
  
  df <- 
    mpg %>% 
    filter(cty > 25)
    
  runApp(shinyApp(
    ui = fluidPage(
      numericInput("x", "# of obs.", 20),
      plotOutput("plot")
    ),
    server = function(input, output) {
      my_df <- reactive({
        head(cars, input$x)
      })
      
      output$plot <- renderPlot(
        plot(my_df())
      )
    }
  ))'
```

I want to return this code:

```
my_df <- reactive({
  head(cars, input$x)
})

output$plot <- renderPlot(
  plot(my_df())
)
```

I'm currently using a mix of `parse()` and my [guts()](https://github.com/rjake/shinyobjects/blob/6500b0b6213ebfbb9ff9326fd80071cccf4bf080/R/utilites-find-server-code.R#L117-L125) function but imagine there is a better way.

Also, where can I learn more about this? Is there anything in `rlang` or `purrr` that makes it easier?

Comment: Something like `as.list(parse(text=code))[[c(1,2,3,3)]]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this without using `parse` using `str2lang` from base R:

```
str2lang(code)[[2]][3][[1]][3][[1]]
#> {
#>     my_df <- reactive({
#>         head(cars, input$x)
#>    })
#>    output$plot <- renderPlot(plot(my_df()))
#> }
```

---

**Edit**

With the updated code string, there are 4 expressions to be parsed instead of 1, so we need to use `as.list(parse(text))` and subset the results:

```
as.list(parse(text = code))[[4]][[2]][3][[1]][3][[1]]
#> {
#>     my_df <- reactive({
#>         head(cars, input$x)
#>    })
#>    output$plot <- renderPlot(plot(my_df()))
#> }
```

Comment: This gets me very close. I updated my code example as I might have more expressions than just `shinyApp()`. Could you take another crack at it?